# Rest queries in SP2010 with $top and $skip

Tags: 2010, rest, query

I have been reading up on Rest queries for SP2010, but at the moment I dont have an enviroment to test on.

would these two queries return items 10-19 of the Example list?

```
var test1= siteUrl + "_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Example $skip=10&$top=10"

var test2= siteUrl + "_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Example(19) $skip=10"
```

if they both return items 10-19, which is the most efficient?

any tips on the easiest way of testing sp2010 compatible queries is appreciated

EDIT:

I was able to run tests at odata.org

I used this query:
http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$skip=2&$top=3

and the result was products 2,3 and 4. it skipped products 0 and 1.

that means that _vti_bin/ListData.svc/Example?$skip=10&$top=10 would return items 10-19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When you request for a specific item (`Example(19)`) you can't use `$skip` or `$top`.
- The `$skip` and `$top` parameters must be passed in as [querystrings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/querystring).
- Remember to start at root path (/), so `siteUrl` must end with /.

.

```
var siteUrl = "/somesite/";
var test1 = siteUrl + "_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Example?$skip=10&$top=10"
var test2 = siteUrl + "_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Example(19)"
```

Comment: ok, that clears up all doubts on the second query. just one more thing i want to clear up, would $skip=10&$top=10 bring back results 10-19 or 11-20?

Comment: I found the answer to the question in my last comment. I will edit my question with my findings.